# wp_unique_post_slug is not unique

Tags: permalinks

I understand that the `post` post_type is not the same as `page` but when editing the permalink for a new post to be the same as the slug for an existing page, it's accepted. I now have a post and a page both with `wordpress/sample-page` set as the permalink. The link opens that of the page, I guess pages are looked for first.

Surely this can't be normal behaviour. This is on 6.3.1 and 6.3 if anybody cares to test.

Is this a bug in the core?

Comment: You got the answer in the question. Slug is unique per post type. So having a page and a post shares same slug it's perfeclty normal and accepted. The url conflict is a problem in your configuration... don't use `/%postname%/` as permalink structure for posts, [that is always a good practise](http://digwp.com/2011/06/dont-use-postname/).

Comment: @G.M. What's the point of a unique per post type when at the end of the day they are used to create urls which can't point to more than one location?

Comment: I don't know why WP works in this way, I know that's so. You can reasonbly think that is a wrong way, but this will not help to make your site works... Joking apart, WP tend to have different permalink structure to speed up the assignation from an url to the right page. Using `/%postname%/` as permastruct, only way for WP to know if the url is for a page or for a post is run a db query that slow down the page load. Maybe the *issue* you found is a way to force users not using same permastruct for pages and posts.

Comment: You can use the `'wp_unique_post_slug'` filter to change the output of the [`wp_unique_post_slug()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unique_post_slug) function which is responsible for creating post and page slugs.